# Cumulus CI: Automate Data Operations to associate parent record with child

Tags: cumulusci

I was going through the documentation to automate data operation by loading the dataset that I am currently working on. Everything looks fine, but there is a use case where I am stuck.

There is a scenario where an Account record can have a parent account. In this case,

```
Insert Account:
    sf_object: Account
    table: Account
    fields:
        Id: sf_id
        Name: Name
        Order__c: Order__c
    lookups:
        Parent__c:
            table: Account
```

And this is in the SQL file:

```
CREATE TABLE "Account" (
    sf_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "Name" VARCHAR(255),
    "Order__c" VARCHAR(255),
    Parent__c VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (sf_id)
);
INSERT INTO "Account" VALUES(1,'ACC-1','1','');
INSERT INTO "Account" VALUES(2,'ACC-2','2',1);
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
Error: 'Account_sf_ids'
```

I believe this error is due to the fact that when the account records are being inserted, we don't have the Id of the 1st Account yet which I can associate with 2nd record.

Is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclosure: I am on the CumulusCI team and I wrote the code that does this type of data load*.

Yes, you can load Account hierarchies and other hierarchies using CumulusCI. CumulusCI executes this as two operations: a load, with all of the `ParentId` fields `null`, followed by an update to populate `ParentId` fields mapped to the Ids of the newly-inserted records.

You instruct CumulusCI to do this by using an `after:` declaration on a relationship. There's an example in [this section](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data.html#defining-datasets) of the documentation:

```yaml
Accounts:
    sf_object: Account
    fields:
        - Name
        - Description
        - RecordTypeId
    lookups:
        ParentId:
            table: Account
            after: Accounts
```

To modify your example mapping, you'd do

```yaml
Insert Account:
    sf_object: Account
    table: Account
    fields:
        Id: sf_id
        Name: Name
        Order__c: Order__c
    lookups:
        Parent__c:
            table: Account
            after: Insert Account
```

The `after:` declaration takes the name of the step after which the lookup should be populated.

As a side note, you're using some older features in your mapping file that are no longer required. You're welcome, if you wish, to omit the `table:` declaration, the `Id` field, and the `Name: Name` mappings (in favor of a simple list), which gives you a more streamlined definition of your dataset:

```yaml
Insert Account:
    sf_object: Account
    fields:
      - Name
      - Order__c
    lookups:
        Parent__c:
            table: Account
            after: Insert Account
```

Comment: I know about you David, Dan and Ryan told me about you. And I was hoping to get a reply from you only. :)
If this works, I will mark your comment as the answer.

Comment: lookup after: Insert Account seems to be broken with latest cumulusci version 3.84.3 . Any workaround to make this version work?

Comment: @Naga Revert to 3.84.1 until the CumulusCI team fixes it. See open issue in the GitHub repo.